# How to mock config-phase providers for unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-providers

I'm writing a spec that checks a method is called during the config phase of the Angular module under test.

Here's a simplified look at the code being tested:

```
angular.module('core',['services.configAction'])
    .config(function(configAction){
        configAction.deferIntercept(true);
    });
```

What happens above is we define a `core` module that has a single dependency.
Then, in the `config`-block of the `core` module, we call the `deferIntercept` method on the `configAction` object given to use from `services.configAction`.

I'm trying to test that `core`'s config calls that method.

This is the current setup:

```
describe('core',function()
{
    const configActionProvider={
        deferIntercept:jasmine.createSpy('deferIntercept'),
        $get:function(){
            return {/*...*/}
        }
    };

    beforeEach(function()
    {
        module(function($provide)
        {
            $provide.provider('configAction',configActionProvider);
        });

        module('core.AppInitializer');

        inject(function($injector)
        {
            //...
        });
    });

    it('should call deferIntercept',function()
    {
        expect(configActionProvider.deferIntercept).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    });
});
```

The problem with that is that it doesn't override `configAction` and so the spy is never called, the original method is.
It will do so if I remove it as a dependency of the `core` module, so `angular.module('core',[])` instead of `angular.module('core',['services.configAction'])` will work and the spy is called.

Any idea how to override `services.configAction` during testing without removing it from the dependency list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at - https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-config-and-run. 
Something like the following -

```
module('services.configAction', function (configAction) {
  mockConfigAction = configAction;
  spyOn(mockConfigAction, 'deferIntercept').andCallThrough();
});
module('core');
```

in your beforeEach might do the job.

Comment: Thanks. [extra chars]